# Spring Cloud Config Client re-loading config every 30 seconds

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I'm working to enable the use of Spring Cloud Config and have everything working. However, I'm seeing INFO messages in my service app logs that shows that the Cloud Config Client is looking to re-load the configuration from the server about every 30 seconds. I cannot find anything in the docs or even in the code to suggest why this is happening. I really don't want my services polling the config server nearly that often, and ideally I'd like to turn it off, so I have some more control over when a config refresh happens.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'd like a solution to this as well. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: No, I have not had time to dig into what is causing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the `\health` endpoint is called on a config client, it reaches out to the config server to pull new configuration. Service discovery tools like Eureka or Consul poll said endpoint, causing this issue.

You can stop the config client from reaching out to the config server by setting this property in your bootstrap.yml/bootstrap.properties:

```
health.config.enabled=false
```

[Taken from here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/423)

Comment: Yep, I just figured that out the other day and forgot to answer my question. Thanks!

Comment: If my answer solved the problem, would you mind accepting it?

Comment: Is there a way I configure my client to poll config server for a certain time interval?

Comment: bootstrap.yml is deprecated in newer Spring boot versions (2.4+). All the configs should be moved to application.(yml|properties) in the new versions.